# HighChart is preventing click event on a parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, highcharts

I am building a table where when cell is clicked high charts is shown in its place(same way as flip cards). And when highchart is clicked a cell is reverted back it is original state. 

However, after creating a chart dynamically all my click functions on a parent stop working when clicking on a chart directly. 
I have created this small jsFiddle to demonstrate my problem:
    http://jsfiddle.net/2j4qQ/2/

Code:`$('#contentDiv').on('click', '.homepageChart', function() {});`
    $('#contentDiv').on('click', '.homepageChart', function() {});
This function does not fire when clicking directly on a chart. Why? and how can it be 

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added an overlay with `z-index:1;` to my highcharts which seems to solve the problem. However, this seems incorrect, since i should be able to listen to dynamically created highcharts events. If anyone has some info on this please share. 
Here is updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2j4qQ/5/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this: [jsfiddle.net/cssimsek/4Wa32/1](http://jsfiddle.net/cssimsek/4Wa32/1/). Since you were appending the Highcharts `<div>` with each click I added the `.detach()` method to the callback function of the `.hide()`method, in order to remove the `<div>` on secondary clicks. It seems to be working ok now.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking a look. However, it still does not work. When I click on a chart, it is not being hidden and `onDivClick` is not invoked.

Comment: Hi, yeah sorry my fix only goes as far as to allow showing and hiding of the chart when `#contentDiv` is clicked, rather than when the newly  appended `<div>` is clicked. With the latest fiddle you shared, removing the z-index properties doesn't appear to make any difference. So it appears that you're solving the issue by appending a sibling element (`.chartOverlay`) along with the `div` which encloses the chart. It seems like it may be a propagation issue..

Comment: @fasola81 - You may also want to have a look at this related [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618075/highcharts-stop-chart-from-trapping-mouse-events-or-capture-mouse-click-on-the) thread.